# Perform cross transformations for all except current value

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have the following dataset:

```
ID  Animal
1   Dog
1   Cat
1   Turtle
2   Turkey
2   Dog
2   Cat
3   Tiger
3   Antelope
```

My goal here is to essentially create a crosstab, however I want to treat each combination of ID and animal as a unique ID, such taht i'd get the following output.

[image]

I'm using python2.7 unfortunately so it'll have to be compatible there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.get_dummies`, and `join` outcome to dataframe

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.Animal))



    ID    Animal  Antelope  Cat  Dog  Tiger  Turkey  Turtle
0   1       Dog         0    0    1      0       0       0
1   1       Cat         0    1    0      0       0       0
2   1    Turtle         0    0    0      0       0       1
3   2    Turkey         0    0    0      0       1       0
4   2       Dog         0    0    1      0       0       0
5   2       Cat         0    1    0      0       0       0
6   3     Tiger         0    0    0      1       0       0
7   3  Antelope         1    0    0      0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot and then fill with concat

```
df = pd.concat([df,df.pivot(columns='animal',values='animal').notnull().astype('int').fillna(0)],axis=1)
print(df)
```